# Comparison of two images taken in different environments using OpenCV-python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

I have to compare two images of the same object taken in different surrounding light (for example one in bright sunlight, other in white light, etc.) and the camera angle is rotated as well as the sizes may be different. Now as the images are of the same object, they should match almost correctly. The comparison is to be done on the basis of color and shape. For this the test image needs to be rescaled, rotated and the difference in the light should be compensated. Please tell me how to do it using OpenCV-python. I am using OpenCV 3.0.0 and python 2.7.
I have attached sample images of the same object to be compared.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

I am really not getting any good method that will do the job. Please help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show some of the work you already done (code..).
Do you want to solve only this case? Do you want some automatic algorithm for a specific case? Does the images are always of yellow rectangle on a white background?

Comment: I have tried using homography, feature matching, etc. But none of them work as desired. The algorithm should be general and not specific to only this test case. The image can be of any shape (or combination of various shapes), like a simple painting of a fruit bowl. The background can be of any color, not only white but the painting can be distinguished from the background.

Comment: I think the problem with feature matching is that you don't have any... It's a blank yellow rectangle. In case of an image it will be much easier to do feature matching.
If you don't have any feautres, try looking on contours, find their orientation and scale. Of course there is also some ambiguity for circles, rectangles, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Try matching the images using an interest point detector like ORB or SIFT. The following is the result using ORB.

[image]

Code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img1 = cv2.imread('im1.jpg',0) 
img2 = cv2.imread('im2.jpg',0) 

orb = cv2.ORB_create()

kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = bf.knnMatch(des1,des2, k=2)

good = []
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.95*n.distance:
        good.append([m])

img3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,good, None,flags=2)


plt.imshow(img3),plt.show()
```

Comment: It doesn't give me the angle through which the second image is to be rotated and the scaling factor so that the two shapes match best. Also, how to check if their colors match?

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments, in case of objects with no distinct features like in this example, I would suggest using geometrical features:

- Remove the background (Create binary image with only object vs. background)
- Find the outer contour
- Find its orientation, size, center
- Rotate and scale the images
- If you have some projection (image not taken directly from above), you could use some algorithms for shape matching to find correspondence between points and then estimate homography from them.

Then, when your images are aligned, you could use any correlation for the comparison. Have a look at this tutorial [Histogram Comparison](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d8/dc8/tutorial_histogram_comparison.html).

Comment: Can you please provide code for rotation and scaling so that the two images match best?

Comment: @ath - OpenCV has [EstimateRigidTransform](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#estimaterigidtransform), which finds the optimal transformation. After you find it you can call [warpAffine](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga0203d9ee5fcd28d40dbc4a1ea4451983) to apply the transformation on the image.